# range index on mixed content node in exist db

Tags: xquery, exist-db

My xml file is with the structure

```
<root>
    <compound>abc<parts>a b c</parts></compound>
    <compound>xyz<parts>x y z</parts></compound>
</root>
```

I have created a range index on

```
<range>
    <create qname="compound" type="xs:string"/>
</range>
```

I expected the index terms are `abca` `b` `c` and `xyzx` `y` `z` but I found `abc` and `xyz` under index link in monitoring and profiling window. And also the search string

```
//compound[.="abca b c"] giving 0 results.
```

Can any one help in creating index on the whole contents of compound like on `abca` `b` `c`, `xyz` `x` `y` `z` so on..

Thanks

sony

Answer (score 0):

In xquery, you have to use `data()` function in order to return all of the descendant or the sub-element values. 
So, to test if the values of the `compound` element can be returned you can use the following:

```
//compound/data()[.="abca b c"]
```

Comment: but does it use the index created on <compound> node

Comment: you can have a try! 
The marklogic documentation for the fn:data() function: https://docs.marklogic.com/fn:data

Answer (score 0):

```
 nested="yes" attribute solved the problem.
```

I have changed the range index to

```
<range>
    <create qname="compound" type="xs:string" nested="yes" />
</range>
```

Comment: If this is the answer, would you please mark it as such? Otherwise, the question shows up as "unanswered."